# auto-returning functions and template instantiation

Tags: c++, c++14

While writing some template code, I ran into `<unresolved overloaded function type>` errors which can be reduced to the following.

```
template <int N>
auto bar()
{
    return N;
}

int main(int, char* [])
{
    auto foo = [] (auto func) {
            return func();
        };

    foo(bar<3>);
}
```

With the errors being:

```
unresolved_overload.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
unresolved_overload.cpp:26:28: error: no match for call to '(main(int, char**)::<lambda(auto:1)>) (<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
     std::cout << foo(bar<3>) << std::endl;
                            ^
unresolved_overload.cpp:21:29: note: candidate: template<class auto:1> constexpr main(int, char**)::<lambda(auto:1)>::operator decltype (((const main(int, char**)::<lambda(auto:1)>*)((const main(int, char**)::<lambda(auto:1)>* const)0))->operator()(static_cast<auto:1&&>(<anonymous>))) (*)(auto:1)() const
     auto foo = [] (auto func) {
                             ^
unresolved_overload.cpp:21:29: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
unresolved_overload.cpp:26:28: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'auto:1'
     std::cout << foo(bar<3>) << std::endl;
                            ^
unresolved_overload.cpp:21:29: note: candidate: template<class auto:1> main(int, char**)::<lambda(auto:1)>
     auto foo = [] (auto func) {
                             ^
unresolved_overload.cpp:21:29: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
unresolved_overload.cpp:26:28: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'auto:1'
     std::cout << foo(bar<3>) << std::endl;
```

If we replace the auto-return with the explicit return type, `int`, the example will compile fine.

Why does auto-return run into these issues? I looked into template argument deduction and substitution but the search was largely unfruitful. I thought it might have something to do with the order of template instantiation / etc but couldn't make too much sense of it...

Comment: gcc fails to compile the shown code, reporting this error message, but `auto z=bar<3>; foo(z);` seems to work fine, which makes me point the finger at the compiler.

Comment: The compilation fails in Clang too. Anyway, I suspect the reason you cannot do this is the same reason why you cannot do `transform(..., max<int>)`. You need to explicitly cast what overload you want or wrap it inside a functor.

Comment: @user167921 I did not actually test this with Clang but godbolt indicates that it does compile https://godbolt.org/g/jjapKh. Could you perhaps elaborate on explicitly casting the overload?

Comment: use decltype in the template function definition

Comment: I should think this should compile. Technically you should be using `&bar<3>`, but it makes no difference in gcc. Surprisingly this compiles in MSVC 19.00.23506. Also compiles in Clang 7.0

Comment: @user167921: What version of clang are you trying to compile with? It works in clang 5 and clang 7. Also, since OP is already specifying the template instantation they want, no cast should be necessary.

Comment: @Lawrence: Simply assigning the instantiation to a variable first appears to be a workaround for what is almost certainly a GCC bug (searching the bug list to see if it's been reported already) [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0vRgq0qePAiS7fAy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per AndyG's suggestion, I found the same issue on GCC's bug list. [Bug 64194](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64194). First reported in 2014. Thus the conclusion seems to be that this is a GCC bug and thankfully not another special case for templates.

Working around this just requires having something else to trigger the instantiation (e.g. assign to a variable, a `using` declaration).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
template <typename func>
auto bar(func&& f)->decltype(f())
{   
    return f();
}


int main()
{
    int i = 100;
    auto f = [=]()
    {
      return i;
    };

    bar(f);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but I do not believe this answers the question. I also do not believe this is a proper workaround for OPs issue.